# Package for testing models on unseen data

Tags: r

I am wondering what packages are out there that can split my data.

I would prefer to optimize my model on 2/3rds of the data. 
Then run it over the last 1/3rd to see how well it holds up.

Also this might sound like a stupid question... but in order to forward run the optimized model over the last 1/3/rd of data, is there a way to do that? Otherwise I am backtesting again right? Idea is to forward test it over the last 1/3rd of data much like it would be seeing real live data.... if im making sense.

Is there a R package out there that can do this?

**Apprecaite the answers.

It would seem in this case that its a relativley simple task with the following steps:

1. Optimize the model to the first 2/3rds of the data.
2. Test those parameters on the last 1/3rd of the data.

This is in contrast to testing and optimizing a model over the entire sample size. This way the model gets to see unseen data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are packages, but depending on what your requirements are, you can do this using base R's extraction operators. It sounds like your using time series or some kind of ordered observation.

After you have your data, create a training index. 
Next, subset your data by the training index to create your training set.
Then create your test set by subsetting the data again, but subtracting the train index.

```
data <- data.frame(x=runif(10000), y=runif(10000))

train_index <- 1:(NROW(data)*0.666)

train_set <- data[train_index, ]

test_set <- data[-train_index, ]
```

In addition, the `caret` package is very popular and has a `train` function that has many addition arguments for implementing sampling techniques of varying sophistication levels, depending on the model and data you are using. If you haven't used it, check it out.

If you are working with time series, the `forecast` package has two function that might be of interest, `CVar` and `tsCV`, although they will not split your data in the manner you require, they will train your data on a rolling basis which is more relevant for some time series models.

Good luck!

Comment: Ok great - i didn't know could subset like that using the .666 multiplier per nrow to actually make a 2/3rd. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are a few packages out that can help with this.  The `caTools` package has a function called `sample.split` specifically for splitting a dataset into testing and training sets.

See: [sample.split documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caTools/versions/1.17.1/topics/sample.split)

You pass in a column in your dataset as the first argument (typically the response variable) and it splits the dataset proportionally among the values in that variable.  That's helpful in case you have a response variable that maybe only comes up some value 5% of the time, you would like your training and testing set to both have a similar representation of that value in each.  It can be used like:

```
split = sample.split(wikiWords$Vandal, SplitRatio = 2/3)
wikitrain = subset(wikiWords, split == TRUE)
wikitest = subset(wikiWords, split == FALSE)
```